Изменения в публикации дампа данных сайтов StackExchange
Компания объявила об изменениях в публикации дампа данных сайтов StackExchange. Дамп данных - это архив с содержимым сайтов в формате XML, по структуре похожий на таблицы в Data Explorer. Раньше он заливался на сторонний ресурс, теперь будет специальный раздел в профиле для его скачивания. На данный момент, по слухам, новый механизм включен для 2% пользователей в качестве теста (у меня не отображается). Это уже вызвало драму: Creative Commons License (BY-SA) Violation: Data dump must not force users to agree to additional terms.
Новые строки в Traducir также появились: https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=dump. Нужно будет их перевести, а для начала определиться, как сам термин будет переводиться, раньше его не было в строках. "Дамп данных", или "Набор данных"?
Добавлено: Также появилась непереведенная страница справки How do I access a data dump for a Stack Exchange site?

"Дамп данных", по-моему, вполне подходит.

Перевёл все строки, которые выдавались по поиску. Оценивайте, редакторы.

Немного подкорректировал и утвердил предложенные строки. Ожидаем в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2024.8.7.13696
У меня пока выглядит так (ссылка на страницу настроек):




Строки применились. В одной нашел неточность, там используется условный оборот с should, поэтому оно не должно переводиться как "обязан". Посмотрите новое предложение: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20864

@MSDN.WhiteKnight утвердил
